# Python3, word2vec, How can I get the list of similarity rank about "price" in my model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, similarity, cosine-similarity

In gensim's word2vec python, I want to get the list of cosine similarity for "price".

I read the document of gensim word2vec, but document it describes `most_similar` and `n_similarity` function)()

I want the whole list of similarity between price and all others.

Comment: do you want to find all words that are similar to the word "price" or what do you want?

Comment: @eugen, yes! find all words that similar to "price", in detail the rank up to 30,000 words.

Comment: @NORU maybe you want to check out this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818426/get-most-similar-words-given-the-vector-of-the-word-not-the-word-itself

Comment: @lahsuk, Thanks lahsuk! it was lazy and silly question. It's ashamed... [similar_by_vector] was what I want to find! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `wv.most_similar('price', topn=len(wv))`, with a `topn` argument of the full vocabulary count of your model, you'll get back a ranked list of every word's similarity to `'price'`.

If you call with `topn=0`, you'll get the raw similarities with all model words, unsorted (in the order the words appear inside `wv.index2entity`).